# How to disable the background when sidenav is opened

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using angular material sidenav for some application settings functionality to achieve something like we have in Google.
[image]
The difference is I am calling this sidenav from another component  and wrapping the router too so that it should open below the application Header.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="main-sidenav">
      <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
    
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

[image]

The problem is when I open the sidenav It does not disable the background. It should automatically implement the backdrop style. Is there any way I can explicitly provide some style for the same or should we consider some different component? Please suggest. Below is the sample stackblitz example for the same scenario

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3iczcv)

Comment: Please [check this example at the official documentation for AngularMaterial](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples#sidenav-backdrop)

Comment: @SomerandomITboy - I followed the same steps too but still no backdrop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `hasBackdrop` flag to `true` in your html:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="main-sidenav" hasBackdrop="true">
      <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
    
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

Per Material doc of [sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api):
[image]

Using your stackblitz, I have confirmed the backdrop renders by inspecting the elements:

[image]

But you are not seeing the dark shadow, because of missing css. To fix this, add following in your `styles.css` file.

```
.mat-drawer-backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Also, to make the sidenav appear like the screenshot in your question, you need to add some css properties in `sidenav` class.

```
.sidenav {
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

Result:

[image]

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-arjdpv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: It did not work

Comment: I have updated the answer, see the latest example.